# How to shorten Python for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, simplify

I have created a for loop and I wanted to simplify my loop further. These are the codes that I have written for my for loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    reported_claims.iloc[i,(i+1)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[0]
    reported_claims.iloc[i,(i+2)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[1]
    reported_claims.iloc[i,(i+3)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[2]
```

and I received this output:
[image]

I have tried 2 ways to simplify my for loop:

```
n = 1
j = 0
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    reported_claims.iloc[i,(i+n)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[j]; n+=1; j+=1
```

```
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    for j in range(0,len(chance)):
        for n in range(1,4):
            reported_claims.iloc[i,(i+n)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[j]
```

But the outputs that I received did not match with my original one:

[image]

[image]

Could anyone please advice me how I can simplify my original for loop? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    for j in range(0,len(chance)):
                reported_claims.iloc[i,j+1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[j]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried the codes but it didn't match with my orginal output unfortunately.

Comment: what about replacing third line with this: reported_claims.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[j] ?

Comment: I tried it. The numbers are correct but they're vertical instead of diagonal like my orinignal output.

Comment: Actually I have got it working now by adding (i + 1) - 1 to j in the third line. Thank you so much for your help!    reported_claims.iloc[i,(j+i+1)-1] = df.iloc[i, 1] * df.iloc[i, 2] * chance[j]

Comment: you're welcome, for your future possible questions try mentioning a brief schema of problem so you reach an answer faster .